# Template function doesnt work in a sap.m.Table

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5, web-deployment

I want to call a template function for the items in a table. But I get the following error:

> Assertion failed: list bindings support only a single template object

```xml
<Table 
  id="treeTable"
  items="{path:'nodeModel>/nodeRoot', parameters: {arrayNames:['children']}, template: '.resourceTemplate'}">
  <columns>
    <Column><Text text="Column1"/>
    </Column>
    <Column><Text text="Column2"/>
    </Column>
  </columns>
  <items>
    <ColumnListItem>
      <cells>
        <Text text="Row1Col1"/>
        <Text text="Row1Col2"/>
      </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
  </items>
</Table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define template using XML or JS only:

```
<Table 
  id="treeTable"
  items="{path:'nodeModel>/nodeRoot', parameters: {arrayNames:['children']}, template: '.resourceTemplate'}">
  <columns>
    <Column><Text text="Column1"/>
    </Column>
    <Column><Text text="Column2"/>
    </Column>
  </columns>
</Table>
```